# How to properly use capture reference in R using grepl function

Tags: r

I'm trying to find all the set of strings with two consecutive repeated words like "the the", "air air". I'm using grepl function in R and my code look like this:

```
grepl("[a-zA-Z]+\\s+\1", c("the the", "Humbert Humbert", "air water"), perl = TRUE)
```

> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

The strings "the the" and "air air" should return TRUE but it returns FALSE which is I don't know why.

Is there anything missing in my code? Please help me.

Comment: `grepl("([a-zA-Z]+)\\s+\\1", c("the the", "Humbert Humbert", "air water"))`

Comment: You are close. In R you need to use \\1 instead of \1 (two backslashes). Also you are missing the capturing parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine.